# populate yaml variable from jinja variable

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I want to populate the `nifi.web.https.host` below after I run the below playbook. I am new to ansible jinja/yaml so I am not sure why is not working.

```
{% set external_ip =  'curl 169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/public-ipv4' %}
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  roles:
    - my.nifi
  vars:
    nifi_properties:
      # HTTPS properties
      nifi.web.https.host: 'external_ip'
      nifi.web.https.port: 8443
      nifi.web.https.network.interface.default: eth0
```

After I run the playbook I get this error:

```
{% set external_ip =  'curl 169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/public-ipv4' %}
```

^ here

Comment: Playbooks are written in YAML syntax. See this [intro](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html). You cannot have direct Jinja statements in playbooks, that's what the error is about. You'll need to run tasks (`pre_tasks`) and `register` the output for this.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me understand what was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  roles:
    - my.nifi

  pre_tasks:
     - name: Get EC2 public IP
       raw:  curl http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/public-ipv4
       register: ec2_public_ip

  vars:
    nifi_properties:
      # HTTPS properties
      nifi.web.https.host: "{{ ec2_public_ip.stdout }}"
      nifi.web.https.port: 8443
      nifi.web.https.network.interface.default: eth0
```